# I want to copy the $friendname=$_POST['friendname']; value to the next page when if statement works and echo there

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to copy friendname from this page  to the next page and echo there .
the problem is that it is showinh undefined vairable .
The goal is to echo the same friendname value to the next page i.e form2.php and echo there

```
<?php

    include("config.php");
    session_start();
    $user=$_POST['username'];//username
    $friendname=$_POST['friendname'];//friendname
    $years=$_POST['years'];
    $nickname=$_POST['nickname'];
    $place=$_POST['place'];//username

    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (username,friendname,years,nickname,place)
                VALUES ('$user', '$friendname', '$years','$nickname','$place')";




    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $_POST['friendname']=$frnd;//username
        header('location: ../form2.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }
    $con->close();
?>
```

this is what i have tried but not working
insert.php

```
<?php


    include("config.php");
    session_start();
    $user=$_POST['username'];//username
    $friendname=$_POST['friendname'];//friendname
    $years=$_POST['years']
    $nickname=$_POST['nickname'];
    $place=$_POST['place'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO data (username,friendname,years,nickname,place)
            VALUES ('$user', '$friendname', '$years','$nickname','$place')";

    if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        $_POST['friendname']=$frnd;//username
        header('location: ../form2.php');
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }
    $con->close();
?>
```

form2.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    }
    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {

    }
?>




<html>
    <body>
        <p><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>
        <h4>Enter some details for your friend <?php echo $frnd;?></h4>
        <form>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

NOtice:undefined index variable frnd on line number

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: The error is clear - in the `form2.php` page you have not created the variable `$frnd` - simple as that. I suspect this is supposed to be assigned the value of `$_SESSION['username']`

Comment: @kironmoy mondal please check it.

Answer (score 0):

**file2.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$frnd = $_SESSION['friendname'];

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <p><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>
        <h4>Enter some details for your friend <?php echo $frnd;?></h4>
        <form>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The sql is wide open to sql injection in the above code - you ought to consider using `prepared statements` as, once mastered, will make life much simpler and your code safer.

The below is not tested but essentially works as follows:

The POST request data is filtered - though this is not strictly necessary when using a prepared statement is, IMO, always a good idea.

The sql is `prepared` for execution and the `?` placeholders in the sql are bound to variables.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include 'config.php';

    $user=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $name=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'friendname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $years=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'years', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
    $nick=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'nickname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    $place=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'place', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    $sql='insert into `data` (`username`,`friendname`,`years`,`nickname`,`place`) values (?,?,?,?,?)';
    $stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );

    if( !$stmt )exit('Failed to prepare SQL query');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssiss',$user,$name,$years,$nick,$place);

    $res=$stmt->execute();

    if( $res && $con->affected_rows==1 ){
        $_SESSION['friendname']=$name;
        $_SESSION['username']=$user;
        exit( header('Location: ../form2.php') );
    } else {
        exit('Error');
    }
?>
```

Then your HTML can be modified like this to assign the session variable to a variable - thogh again not strictly necessary to do that

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $friend = $_SESSION['friendname'];
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <p><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>
            <h4>Enter some details for your friend <?php echo $friend;?></h4>       
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i cannot echo $_SESSION['username']; it is showing undefined index username

Comment: @KIRONMOYMONDAL    yes , because you cannot pass username in session variable.